# Searching For Fantasy love Cartoon

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon about a secret world behind a waterfall guarded by a dragon and it has 12 doors leading to different worlds and the hero is a descendant of the Scottish royal family and is exiled at the beginning of the story from England and the story features his adventures with his beloved blonde princess.

Comment: Do you remember when you watched this? In what country? Was it in English? What era was the Hero from? Was it a medieval world? Futuristic? Steampunk? We have some questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info that may help elicit more information. Editing answers to those questions into your question will help us help you.